# Upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 LTS, Gnome on-screen keyboard not working

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 22.04, python3, 22.10

While upgrading I run into some issues.

I had cleaned up the ppa purge things i had done.

Lenovo P53 with Nvidia stuff that seems to be working according to logs.

```
uname -a 
5.15.0.52-generic  ... #58-Ubuntu
```

This is hate filled doing this on another PC not having my Ubuntu Desktop :(

I'm able to go in as recovery root and `sudo - myuser`.
Prior to the upgrade
had some pretty crazy stuff for foreign lang things for X fonts to work for another project.

the Syslog shows that the OS is doing stuff even the Gnome screen displays (both extra monitors).
keyboard and mouse are frozen.

Where do i start looking?
I've read through the logs and cross referred the guides, where or what should I be looking for for a troubleshooting this?

Comment: the GUI time clock updates, pretty sure it's the X key board stuff. 
keyboard works fine in Recovery mode, running 
X.org X Server 1.21.1.3
does the gnome use X i read it was using like nvidia directly or something. 
/var/log/X.org.0.log says: 
X.Org XInput driver :  24.4 
...
LoadModule "fbdev"
Warning, couldn't load module "fbdev" 
couldn't open module vesa

Comment: looks like there was a focal1 remanent in the apt repos 
i did a full remove and it removed alot...

Comment: had to get a cmd line session for text login: 
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/boot-ubuntu-20-04-command-console
sudo apt remove python3.10-venv and bunches of stuff, 
then sudo apt autoremove a ton more. 
then... reinstall and viola gdm3 
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3

Comment: left over python 3.10 libs ruined the upgrade, i should have removed them.
now the gnome-desktop is having problems with applications not working. the pycharm is working ok. but not chromium, i'm doing a manual removal and re-install, got a slack to install (but i removed it before the work noted above).